# BASH: Get text before string

Tags: bash, shell

how to get text before a delimeter string in Bash? Like:
`str="Hello World! It's a nice Day!"` i need to get everything before `nice`. `echo $str` should show me `Hello World! It's a`
Thank you

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `%` or `%%` operator:

```
$ str="Hello World! It's a nice Day!" ; echo "<${str%%nice *}>"
<Hello World! It's a>
```

This will remove the longest suffix.

See the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter%word}`
>   `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The *word* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of *parameter*, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>   *parameter* with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘`%`’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘`%%`’ case) deleted. If *parameter* is ‘`@`’
>   or ‘`*`’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>   parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
>   *parameter* is an array variable subscripted with ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm!